# Validations using if else and hasClass statements in Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I am trying to validate the set of titles for a component. Below is my Cypress code snippet:

```
it('Validate the titles of all the tiles', () => {
    cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile')
      .each(($el) => {
        if($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--cancelled')) {
            $el.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile-status--cancelled')
               .invoke('text')
               .then((text) => {
                  expect(text).equals('Cancelled')
               })
        } else if($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--pre-game')) {
            $el.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-time--en')
               .invoke('text')
               .then((text) => {
                    const gameTime = text.split(" ").pop()
                    expect(['AM', 'PM']).to.include(gameTime)
               })
        } else if($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--final')) {
            $el.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-time--en')
               .invoke('text')
               .then((text) => {
                   const finalTitle = text.trim()
                   expect(finalTitle).to.be.oneOf(['Final','Final (OT)'])
               })
        } else if($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--ongoing')) {
            $el.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-time--en')
               .invoke('text')
               .then((text) => {
                   const ongoingTitle = text.trim()
                   expect(ongoingTitle).equals('Ongoing')
               })
        }
    })
})
```

But I get an error message: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invoke')'.

It works fine if I try it with only if block.

Comment: One of the `$el.get()` calls is returning `undefined`.

Comment: BTW `$el.get()` is for fetching data from the server - [ref](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten it a bit with jQuery operators.

`$el.find(...)` works since $el is a jQuery object.

Also change `.invoke('text')` to `.text()`.

```js
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile')
  .each(($el) => {

    if ($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--cancelled')) {

      // can work with jQuery operators here
      const text = $el.find('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile-status--cancelled').text()
      expect(text).equals('Cancelled')
    }

    if ($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--pre-game')) {
      const text = $el.find('.bms-scoreboard__game-time--en').text()
      const gameTime = text.split(" ").pop()
      expect(['AM', 'PM']).to.include(gameTime)
    }

    if ($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--final')) {
      const text = $el.find('.bms-scoreboard__game-time--en').text()
      const finalTitle = text.trim()
      expect(finalTitle).to.be.oneOf(['Final','Final (OT)'])
    }

    if ($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--ongoing')) {
      const text = $el.find('.bms-scoreboard__game-time--en').text()
      const ongoingTitle = text.trim()
      expect(ongoingTitle).equals('Ongoing')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time that you are doing `$el.get()`, you should be wrapping the `$el` before doing the `.get()`, because when `$el` is yielded from your initial `cy.get()`, it is a `JQuery<HTMLElement>`, and thus out of the Cypress chain.

Additionally, once you wrap `$el`, you can use `.find()` to search within the wrapped element.

```js
cy.get('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile')
      .each(($el) => {
        if($el.hasClass('bms-scoreboard__game-tile--cancelled')) {
             cy.wrap($el)
               .find('.bms-scoreboard__game-tile-status--cancelled')
               .invoke('text')
               .then((text) => {
                  expect(text).equals('Cancelled')
               })
...
```